# Declarative argument validation in java with AspectJ

Tags: java, validation, annotations, aspectj

Are there any existing libraries for declarative argument validation with AspectJ?

Some example code i'm using now :

```
public void someFunction(Object first, Object second){
    condition(notEqual(first,second), "exception message");
    //...
}
```

condition() is the only method throwing exception, all other validation methods return booleans... somehting similar to spring or apache validation utils...

Now with such a technology as AspectJ I'd like to remove all occurrances of similar code with annotations... like this:

```
@Validate({
      "not equal : first, second",
      "not null or empty : first"
})
public void someFunction(Object first, String second){
    //...
}
```

Is there any handy implementations or I should create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually as I couldn't find anything close to what i've described so I've wrote it myself and published on github https://github.com/vach/valida, I'll publish it on maven central repo as soon as my domain is ready.

For now those who might want to try it now :

1. download and extract [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmvly5fs1bicfs1/valida.zip) to your local repo
2. add dependency to pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.vach</groupId>
       <artifactId>valida</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. make sure aspectj weaving is enabled

Answer (score 1):

intellij has a library for static analysis

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/@contract-annotations.html

i dont know if it is open source (it might be, a large part of their code base is), and whether or not you could use it in your advice, or whether it would be worth it (over rolling your own).

of course there is also the venerable javax.validation package, that is part of javaEE6/7. there should be lots of open source implementations of that. and you should be able to annotate actual method parameters. you will have to write your own advice, but the validation could be handed off.